# In Perl, what is the most reliable way to determine a coderef's package?

Tags: perl, higher-order-functions

I have a number of higher order utility functions that take in a code reference and apply that code to some data.  Some of these functions require localizing variables during the execution of the subroutines.  At the beginning, I was using `caller` to determine which package to localize into, in a similar manner as shown in this example `reduce` function:

```
sub reduce (&@) {
    my $code      = shift;
    my $caller    = caller;
    my ($ca, $cb) = do {
        no strict 'refs';
        map \*{$caller.'::'.$_} => qw(a b)
    };
    local (*a, *b) = local (*$ca, *$cb);
    $a = shift;
    while (@_) {
        $b = shift;
        $a = $code->()
    }
    $a
}
```

Initially this technique worked fine, however as soon as I tried writing a wrapper function around the higher order function, figuring out the correct caller becomes complicated.

```
sub reduce_ref (&$) {&reduce($_[0], @{$_[1]})}
```

Now in order for `reduce` to work, I would need something like:

```
    my ($ca, $cb) = do {
        my $caller = 0;
        $caller++ while caller($caller) =~ /^This::Package/;
        no strict 'refs';
        map \*{caller($caller).'::'.$_} => qw(a b)
    };
```

At this point it became a question of which packages to skip, combined with the discipline of never using the function from within those packages.  There had to be a better way.

It turns out that the subroutine the higher order functions take as an argument contains enough meta-data to solve the problem.  My current solution is using the `B` introspection module to determine the compiling stash of the passed in subroutine.  That way, no-matter what happens between compilation of the code and its execution, the higher order function always knows the correct package to localize into.

```
    my ($ca, $cb) = do {
        require B;
        my $caller = B::svref_2object($code)->STASH->NAME;
        no strict 'refs';
        map \*{$caller.'::'.$_} => qw(a b)
    };
```

So my ultimate question is if this is the best way of determining the caller's package in this situation?  Is there some other way that I have not thought of?  Is there some bug waiting to happen with my current solution?

Comment: This seems to be awfully implementation-dependent...  How confident are you that none of this will change in future versions of Perl?  Would it not be simpler and more robust to use objects instead of raw functions, having each object store a function and also remember the appropriate package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can use the following and not need any changes:

```
sub reduce_ref (&$) { @_ = ( $_[0], @{$_[1]} ); goto &reduce; }
```

But generally speaking, the following is indeed exactly what you want:

```
B::svref_2object($code)->STASH->NAME
```

You want the `$a` and `$b` variables of the sub's `__PACKAGE__`, so you want to know the sub's `__PACKAGE__`, and that's exactly what that returns. It even fixes the following:

```
{
   package Utils;
   sub mk_some_reducer {
      ...
      return sub { ... $a ... $b ... };
   }
}

reduce(mk_some_reducer(...), ...)
```

It doesn't fix everything, but that's impossible without using arguments instead of `$a` and `$b`.

Comment: I knew someone was going to mention the `goto &sub` workaround :)  It is my usual solution, but in this case the real wrappers either need to localize other variables, or need to post process the results from the HOF.  Regarding Nemo's comment above about the stability of the `->STASH->NAME` interface, do you think it is safe to assume that the B interface will not change?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needs them, here are the functions that I eventually decided to use:

```
require B;
use Scalar::Util 'reftype';
use Carp 'croak';

my $cv_caller = sub {
    reftype($_[0]) eq 'CODE' or croak "not code: $_[0]";
    B::svref_2object($_[0])->STASH->NAME
};

my $cv_local = sub {
    my $caller = shift->$cv_caller;
    no strict 'refs';
    my @ret = map \*{$caller.'::'.$_} => @_;
    wantarray ? @ret : pop @ret
};
```

Which would be used as:

```
my ($ca, $cb) = $code->$cv_local(qw(a b));
```

in the context of the original question.